# Is it possible to disable the auto-instantiation behaviour of the UnityContainer?

Tags: .net, unity-container, ioc-container

UnityContainer.Resolve() will instantiate classes that have not been explicitly registered by means of reflection, allowing this sort of thing:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
            foo.SayHello();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, it is possible to disable this behaviour if I want to, so that the class is not automatically resolved (with either an exception being raised, or a null being returned?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built in, but you could write a container extension which would change this behavior. It would require two things - first off, a handler for the registering event that recording when a type was registered in the policy list, and second, a strategy that would check the "is registered" policy and throw if it's not there.

Its fairly small & easy to do if you're familiar with writing extensions. Unfortunately I don't have the time to put one together right now, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. Chris that points me in the right direction, thanks very much.

Comment: An example of such an extension can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31421366/1988326

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Resolve<>()` by passing a registration name, as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660853%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx). So try passing a registration name that does not exist and see what happens. Hopefully that will bypass the reflection logic of Unity and return a `NULL` object.

Comment: Nope, the auto-creation logic remains the same - the name is just a key into the internal registrations list. If it doesn't find anything in the list, the default kicks in.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I'll keep this answer here just in case someone else needs to know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using interfaces. 
Something like this:

```
interface IFoo{...}
class Foo:IFoo{...}
// ...
var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>(); // Exception here
```