# How to prevent resolving unregistered types with Unity container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

As known, when we are trying to resolve unregistered type (class), Unity use constructor of that class. But I'd like to get an exception in that case. How to setup the container for that behavior ?
Thank you.

Comment: So, when you're trying to resolve a class that hasn't been registered you want the container to throw a specific exception?

Comment: @smoksnes, yes, any exception.

Comment: I don't understand. The container will throw an exception if there's no registration for the specific type. "Resolution of the dependency failed". Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: @smoksnes, not always. If you try ti resolve an unnregistered _interface_  the container will throw exception. But if you try to resolve an unregistered _class_ the container will create an instance with the constructor of that class. I don't like it. For example, I've written a class and I want it to be a singleton. But I've forgotten to register it in the container.  Container will throw no exception and I'll know about my mistake too late.

Comment: I see. You can register an UnityContainerExtension. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420619/unity-change-default-lifetime-manager-for-implicit-registrations-and-or-disable

Comment: @smoksnes , thank you !